# Reveal and hide a div on checkbox condition with css

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is reveal and hide a div when the label + checkbox is checked. (CSS only)

So if [Sign Up] is clicked (checked). Hide itself(div.remove-check) and reveal the hidden input (div#email). I thought the code I had would be good enough, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

Html:

```
<div class="remove-check">
    <label for="reveal-email" class="btn" style="width: 300px"><input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button" />Sign Up</label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="email">
    <form id="email-form" class="nice" action="" method="post">
        <input class="input-text required email" type="text" name="EMAIL" id="id_email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="name" id="id_name_email">
        <a class="btn" >Apply</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    visibility: hidden;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .remove-check{
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #email{
    display: block;
}
#email{
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqscu/3/)** to show you what I'm working with.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Currently there are no parent selectors in CSS, which is why that code doesn't work. The checkbox must be on the same level as div in question. [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

---

You can take it out of the label to put them on the same plane like shown here.
This example should work:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.remove-check {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#email {
  display: block;
}

#email {
  display: none;
}


/*  ------ Just styles ------ */

input[type=text] {
  width: 225px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #222222;
}

.btn {
  width: auto;
  background: #2ba6cb;
  border: 1px solid #1e728c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 11px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #006582;
}
```

```html
<label for="reveal-email" class="btn" style="width: 300px"> Sign Up</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="reveal-email" role="button">

<div id="email">
  <form id="email-form" class="nice" action="" method="post">
    <input class="input-text required email" type="text" name="EMAIL" id="id_email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="id_name_email">
    <a class="btn">Apply</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqscu/4/)

Comment: What is the purpose of `<input type="hidden" name="name" id="id_name_email">`?

Comment: It's part of @Modelesq 's original code; not required for functionality.

Comment: Is there a way to animate it, have it slide down with a transition?

Comment: If you want to animate it, you have to change the "display: block/none" parts. You could use CSS animation or transition. Here's an example animating opacity with transition. http://jsfiddle.net/2fbo3Lhe/     Here's an example animating max-height (note you'll want to account for padding).  http://jsfiddle.net/2fbo3Lhe/1/

Answer (score 5):

The `~` CSS selector is called the General Sibling Selector.  It only selects siblings of the preceding selector (not parents or aunts/uncles).

For example:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .remove-check {
    display: none;
}
```

Means:

For any checkboxes that are checked, hide any siblings (elements at the same level in the heirarchy) that have the class remove-check.

There are currently no CSS selectors that apply styles up the chain to the parents.

You will have to either make the checkbox a sibling of the email div or use some non-CSS method (like JavaScript) to do what you want.

Comment: How to make an element the sibling of another? Just by adding an over class above both?