# Set HTML element visibility by radio button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to hide/show a `DIV` based on the state of a radio button.

I know I can add a listener to the radio button and show/hide it whenever it's selected or unselected (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307407/416300) answer).

Is there a way to bind the `Div`'s `display` attribute to the radio-button's `:checked` attribute, something like `$("#myDiv").visibility($("#myRadio").is('checked'));` ?

In other words - can I data-bind the display/visibility to the radio button's state?

Maybe this can be done easily in css?

Comment: `$("#myDiv").toggle($("#myRadio").prop('checked'));`

Comment: Will that change the visibility of `myDiv` every time the button state changes?

Comment: You must wrap this in `radio` button `change` event!

Comment: if you put in in a listener function, you can use `on('change')`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends that what exactly you wants to do with your Div HTML Element:

**Following example is to change Div's Visibility:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#myRadio" ).click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){

            // if you want to change your Div's css property 
            $("#myDiv").css("visibility","hidden");

        }else{

            // Reverting back visibility to visible
            $("#myDiv").css("visibility", "visible");

        }
    });

});
```

**Following example is to change Div's Display:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#myRadio" ).click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){

            // if you want to change your Div's Display None
            $("#myDiv").hide();

        }else{

            // if you want to change your Div's Display BLOCK
            $("#myDiv").show();

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myRadio').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){ 
        $('#myDiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

Above script will check weather radio button is clicked or not on every click

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#myRadio" ).on("change", function() {
        $("#myDiv").css("visibility" ? $(this).is(":checked") ? "visible" : "hidden");
    });

});
```

OR

```
$('#myRadio').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $('#myDiv').show();
     else 
        $('#myDiv').hide();
});
```

On change is technically better than on click, so you aren't running this code when a radio button that is already selected it clicked.  Practically, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a plain CSS solution, you should check out [this Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752134/reveal-and-hide-a-div-on-checkbox-condition-with-css)

Your radio-input needs to be at the same level as the div you want to hide.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="d" id="reveal"><label>reveal it</label>
<input type="radio" name="d" id="hideBack"><label>hide it</label>
<div id="email">
   <form id="email-form" class="nice" action="" method="post">
       <input class="input-text required email" type="text" name="EMAIL" id="id_email" placeholder="Email" />
       <input type="hidden" name="name" id="id_name_email">
       <a class="btn" >Apply</a>
   </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#reveal:not(:checked) ~ #email{
  display: none;
}
#reveal:checked ~ #email{
  display: block;
}
#email{
  display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqscu/589/)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the jquery onchange event with following css

```js
$(function() {
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
   $('#mydiv').toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "mydiv"class = "show-hide"> Hello </div>
<div>
<label>show-hide</label>
<input type="radio" name="show">
</div>
```

Comment: Adding mutually exclusive CSS styles to the same element can unnecessarily complicate your solution and make troubleshooting more difficult.  Granted, it works, but if applied to more complex code, this approach could get hairy very quickly.

Comment: no need for css classes you can just use `toggle` instead of `toggleClass`