# hiding/showing a Div based on a Radio button (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a CSS only Answer, I can solve with Javascript/Jquery but I'm attempting to solve without.

IN short, I have to Radio buttons, I would like one div to be displayed if the first one is selected and a Second div if the second one is selected.

I have Created a jsfiddle with a simplified version of myProblem 
https://jsfiddle.net/lukehammer/x7yw432d/5/ I can not get it to work in the JS fiddle or my code.

```
    <label>
<input id="Type1" name="UserType" type="radio" value="Contractor">
            Contractor
</label>

<label>
<input id="Type2" name="UserType" type="radio" value="Managment">
             Managment
</label>

<div class = "hideAtStart" id = "contractorDisplay">
  Show me I'm a contractor.
</div>

<div class = "hideAtStart" id = "ManagerDisplay">
  Show me I'm a managerr.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hideAtStart {
display: none;
}

#Type1:checked ~ #contractorDisplay{
  display : block; 
}

#Type2:checked ~ #ManagerDisplay{
  display : block; 
}
```

**Question**

How can I show a div when a radio button is pressed ?

**Bonus Points **

BounS Points if the Transition can fade in/out.

Comment: You can do it using either the + selector or ~ selector, however this requires special conditions.

Comment: where can i learn more about these special conditions?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752327/8783706) may help you

Comment: @Willi this is better than anything I found when searching.  The problem I now see is that I had an incorrect understanding of the "~" in CSS meant.  I was assuming that the "~" selected anything. EG #Type2:checked ~ #ManagerDisplay   I thought meant. IF  Type2 is checked then Find #ManagerDisplay and Apply related styling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Layout

1. Set each radio before a div (fieldset in this demo)
2. On each radio:

   - Assign a unique `#id`
   - Assign an identical `[name]`
3. Next make 2 labels with the attribute `[for]` and set each attribute's value to an `#id` of a radio. The `[for]` attribute of the labels are synced to the radio with the same `#id` so that when the label is clicked so is the radio.
4. Place these labels anywhere you want on the page.
5. To make things easier assign a class that will group alike tags together.

---

## Style

1. Hide the radios and the div that sits after each radio by setting `display:none`
2. Make the following ruleset (remember step 5 of Layout)

   ```
    .radio:checked + .classOfDiv { display:block }
   ```

   CSS rulesets are read backwards by the browser:
   Any element that has the className of `.classOfDiv` that has a sibling element that is placed before (in code it's more like above or to the left) it and that sibling (older brother?) has the className of `.radio` *and* happens to be checked as well...set that `.classOfDiv` `display` property to `block`.

   The `+` is called an **Adjacent Sibling Combinator** which is the key to this ruleset. See the References located after the Demo for more details.

---

### Demo

```css
.rad,
.set {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rad:checked+.set {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px inset grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: tomato;
  color: tomato;
  transition: .75s ease;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.5em
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>SWITCH</legend>
    <label for='rad0' class='btn'>OPEN SET 0</label>
    <label for='rad1' class='btn'>OPEN SET 1</label>
  </fieldset>

  <input id='rad0' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>

  <fieldset class='set'>
    <legend>SET 0</legend>
  </fieldset>

  <input id='rad1' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>

  <fieldset class='set'>
    <legend>SET 1</legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### References

[**Adjacent Sibling Combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

[**for** Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for)

Comment: This addresses the Problem.  I need to match the style of other elements that are using radio buttons in the form (extracted out for clarity).

Comment: Is it possible to do this and keep the display of the radio buttons?

Comment: Yes indeed, hiding them is merely for aesthetics. The thing that's critical for them is their position in relation to the div/fieldset. If there's something between them then change the `+` to a `~`.