# Is there a way to get a pop-in animated contact form, but without Javascript or queryselectors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, animation

I was able to make a contact form like this work but I wasn't able to make this work without Javascript. I want the form to pop in from the right side with a click on the "open" icon and then stay open until user closes the form with the "close" icon and then pop out back to the original state. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
const Contact = document.querySelector("#contactForm");

function openForm() {
  Contact.classList.add('open');
}

function closeForm() {
  Contact.classList.add('close');
  setTimeout(function() {
    Contact.classList.remove('open');
    Contact.classList.remove('close');
  }, 300);
}
```

```css
.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #323;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

#contact {
  z-index: 200;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}

#closeContact {
  z-index: 500;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}

#contactForm {
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 400;
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
}

#contactForm.open {
  display: block;
  transition: .5s linear;
  animation-name: formOpen;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#contactForm.close {
  transition: .5s linear;
  animation-name: formClose;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes formClose {
  from {
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: -410px;
  }
}

@keyframes formOpen {
  from {
    right: -300px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.containerContact {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
}

.formheading {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #212529;
}

input[type=text] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  color: #212529;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #212529;
  font-size: 13px;
}

select {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #212529;
  font-size: 13px;
}

select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}

option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}

option {
  color: black;
}

.messageInput {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #212529;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #212529;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  resize: none;
}

.sendButton {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #212529;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #212529;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s
}

.sendButton:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

````html
<button id="contact" type="button" onclick="openForm()"><div class="triangle-left"></div></button>
<div id="contactForm">
  <div class="containerContact">
    <form action="emailsend.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <h3 class="formheading">CONTACT</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit velit ut placerat suscipit.</p> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name or Company*" size="75" autocomplete="on" required>
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" size="75" autocomplete="on" required>
      <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email*" size="75" required>
      <select name="project" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Test*</option>
        <option value="1">Test</option>
        <option value="2">Test</option>
        <option value="3">Test</option>
        <option value="4">Test</option>
        <option value="5">Test</option>
      </select>
      <textarea class="messageInput" name="Message" placeholder="Message*" rows="7" cols="45" required></textarea>
      <input class="sendButton" type="submit" value="Let's Chat!">
    </form>
    <button id="closeContact" type="button" onclick="closeForm()"><div class="triangle-right"></div></button>
  </div>
</div>
```
````

Comment: Yes, by using an Input checkbox, and the CSS `~` selector or by using `:has()`

Comment: Can you give an example where I can see how this would work for my situation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need a solution without JS? Is there any specific reason to it or just for a learning experience?

Comment: Yeah its basically so I can learn to do stuff like this the proper way.

Comment: _"Yeah its basically so I can learn to do stuff like this the proper way."_ - the irony here is, that such "pure CSS solutions" to stuff like this, usually _aren't_ the proper way - they can present massive usability issues for users of assistive technology, such as screen readers. The "correct" way would rather be to do this using JavaScript - **and** implementing the necessary ARIA attributes, to properly communicate changing element states to the users.

Comment: The general principle for the CSS way you can find explained f.e. here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18752134/1427878 But as said, please don't fancy yourself that this would be much of an "improvement", over what you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without JavaScript you could make use of a hidden checkbox and the CSS `:checked` state. Then in order to target the relevant elements use the `~` [subsequent siblings combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator)

```css
#contact {
  z-index: 401;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  transition: rotate 0.6s;
}

#contactForm {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 400;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: translate 0.8s;
  translate: 100% 0;
}

#contact-toggle:checked~#contactForm {
  translate: 0% 0;
}

#contact-toggle:checked~#contact {
  rotate: 180deg;
}

.triangle-left {
  display: inline-block; border-top: 25px solid transparent; border-right: 50px solid #555; border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<input hidden id="contact-toggle" type="checkbox">
<label aria-label="Toggle contact form" id="contact" for="contact-toggle"><span class="triangle-left"></span></label>

<div id="contactForm">
  <div class="containerContact">
    Form here
  </div>
</div>
```